# How to convert via the Coinbase API

Tags: coinbase-api

Within the Coinbase app one can convert digital currencies (see the image below).

[image: coinbase]

But does one convert via the Coinbase or Coinbase Pro API?

Answer (score 0):

Watching API from coinbase webapp i see what endpoint you need to call:

1. Have to know base_id of crypto that you want to sell and base_id of crypto want to buy. You can know it by call GET "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/
   /assets/prices?base=USD&filter=holdable&resolution=latest" and get from response the "base_id" of your currencies.
2. Make an order by calling POST "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/trade" with a request body in json like this:

   {
   'amount': [amount that you want to convert],
   'amount_asset': [currency of amount that you want to convert],
   'amount_from': 'input',
   'source_asset': ["base_id" of crypto that you want to sell],
   'target_asset': ["base_id" of crypto that you want to buy]
   }
3. If previous POST "/trade" response code is 201, you have to get the "id" value of response's json and do a commit of your order by calling POST "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/trades/[id of json response of previous https://api.coinbase.com/v2/trade POST"]/commit". If the response code of this POST commit is 201, your exchange is started and if there are not error in coinbase, your conversion is done!

Comment: That's trading (buy/sell) no ? How about converting ?